Independent indicator variable in regression becomes significant when changing the number of categories
I’m running an logistic regression with a binary response variable. When I use family or not as an indicator variable, being a family has a small, positive but non-significant effect.
When instead checking if the size of the family has an affect by treating it as an categorical variable with 3 levels - single household, medium-sized or a large family, both included dummies are strongly significant and postive compared to the excluded category (single households). Why might this be?
The hypothesis was that not only being a family positively effects the outcome, but also the size of the family. I treated the size of the family as categorical as well because it can only take on 7 different values in the dataset.
(The dataset consists of 425 000 individual of, no repeated measures per individual, but only unfortunately only 7 predictors in total. But the outcome of interest (coded as 1, the other class as 0) is a rare event(only 0.3%) so the data is heavily unbalanced.
43% of the 425 000 individuals belongs to a family. But family households dominate the outcome case of interest - 69% who belongs to outcome = 1 belongs to a family household.
In the 3 categories; 243 000 of all 425 000 in the dataset belongs to a single single household (57%), 30% to a medium-sized household and only 13% to a large family.
However, amongst those belonging to the outcome cash of interest large families now account for 32%, medium for 37% and single for 31 %.)
The coefficient for Family_account is 0.2221, but the p-value is 0.29.
In comparasion, in the model instead using family size the coefficient for Medium_Family is 0.4366 and for Large_family 1.6255 - both with p-values less than 0.000.
Any help is much appreciatead, br

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This might be due to omitted-variabe bias in logistic regression, but it's hard to know without a lot more information. Please edit the question to say more about the size of your data set, how many cases are in each outcome category, the numbers in each of the 3 categories of family, and the number of other predictors. It would also help to show the results of the two models; it might be that the "small, positive but non-significant effect" in the first model isn't that far in practice from the result of the second model.

Thank you for your input EdM, https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28500/edm  I’ve added more information in the question.

What happens if you consider average marginal effects instead of index function coefficients?

To make sure that I've interpreted the details correctly, here are my rough estimates of the numbers of positive cases and total numbers in each group: single, 243,000 total, 395 positive outcome; small family, 121,000 total, 472 positive outcome; large family, 61,000 total, 408 positive outcome. Are those close to correct? I ask because there's ambiguity in the question: it says "43% of the 425 000 individuals belongs to a family, i.e 243 000" which can't both be true.

Apologies for that, it should read” 43% of the 425 000 indivudals belong to a family, i.e. approx. 183 000 indivudals”. I removed the incorrect part.
Otherwise, your numbers are roughly correct (128 000 large family, 55 000 medium family, 243 000 single household). Your numbers in the postive outcome per family size are correct.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28500/edm

Either there is a data/coding problem or there is some association of the other predictors with the family type that is leading to your observation.
As @dimitry suggested in a comment, troubleshooting can start with examining marginal effects by family type, ignoring the other predictors. Based on comments, the following seems to be a summary of those data.
famDF <- data.frame(pos=c(395,472,408),
                    neg=c(243000-395,121000-472,61000-408),
                    type=factor(c("single","small","large"),
                                 levels=c("single","small","large")),
                    famYes=c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE))
famDF
#   pos    neg   type famYes
# 1 395 242605 single  FALSE
# 2 472 120528  small   TRUE
# 3 408  60592  large   TRUE

There's no question that there's a significant association of the binary single/not predictor with the positive outcome, when the other predictors are omitted.
nyModel <- glm(cbind(pos,neg)~famYes,data=famDF,family="binomial")
summary(nyModel)
##
## some output omitted
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept) -6.42030    0.05036 -127.50   <2e-16 
# famYesTRUE   1.09331    0.06064   18.03   <2e-16 

A model by family type (not shown) agrees with your finding increased odds of a positive outcome as you move from single to small to large.
To proceed: check the coding of both the data and the function calls; examine how the other predictors are associated with the single/not status; start with this simple model and add in the other predictors in a slow, deliberate way to evaluate what might be leading to your finding with the full model.

Thank very much for the input! The coding is checked and correct but I’ll proceed to check the correlation.
